# VLOOKUP not finding a value that exists (white space already checked)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, format, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have formulas in google sheets that are performing a VLOOKUP; however, it is not finding the value in my sheet (which is the range within the VLOOKUP formula). I know that the value exists in my other sheet since I can clearly see it, and I am finding no white spaces before or after the values I'm comparing.

Below is image that shows the error. The code is the following: `=VLOOKUP(G68,'Shift Matrix'!A:C,3,false)`

[image: Image of VLOOKUP ERROR]

Below is an image that shows that value I'm searching for exists (with no white space) in my range.

[image: Image of Key Value Existing]

My hypothesis is that it's some sort of formatting issue on my range sheet. When I change it from automatic to plain text, the VLOOKUP will work for that row, but will not work for the other rows that also reference the same search key (66327). The same is true vice versa (changing it back to automatic will result in the same error for that specific row, but the other rows that reference search key 66327 works).

Another key element is that the search key I am using for my VLOOKUP is a product of another VLOOKUP. I'm wondering if that for some reason is also creating a formatting issue (since if I overwrite the VLOOKUP and just type '66327', it works).

Image is shown below and the code is `=IFNA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D92,'LIVE: Seniority Report'!A:O,15,false),VLOOKUP(D92,'LIVE: Termination Report'!B:F,5,false)),"")`

[image: Vlookup Code]

I've never had an issue like this before. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(D92*1, {'LIVE: Seniority Report'!A:A, 'LIVE: Seniority Report'!O:O*1}, 2, 0))
```

Comment: I actually replaced the search key with what you recommended (D92*1), and it worked! Thank you so much